# Typscript Submission Array

Tags: angular, typescript, outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to use microsoft graph to send an event to an attendee filled out in the form I have created with angular, however when sending the submitted data across the array containing the email address, name and the type changes to something that is results in a Error 400.

This error I believe is in regards to the structure changing from what is required.
As shown in image below, the attendees has the [] removed from the value

[image: Text]

How would I maintain the structure in order to successfully submit the post request?

From eventsubmit.component.ts

```
 constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    public graphService: GraphService
  ) {
    this.submitForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      subject: "",
      body: {
          contentType: "HTML",
          content: "Does late morning work for you?"
      },
      start: {
          dateTime: "2020-04-21T12:00:00",
          timeZone: "GMT"
      },
      end: {
          dateTime: "2020-04-21T14:00:00",
          timeZone: "GMT"
      },
      location: {
          displayName: "Harry's Bar"
      },
      attendees: [{
        emailAddress: {
            address: "***@***.com",
            name: "Joe Bloggs"
        },
        type: "required"
    }]
    })
  }

  eventSubmission(eventData) {
    console.log(eventData);
    this.graphService.addnewevent(eventData);
    this.submitForm.reset();
  }
```

from graph.service.ts

```
async addnewevent (eventData) {
    try {
      let responseevents = await this.graphClient.api("/me/events").post(eventData);
      console.log(responseevents);
      return responseevents;
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `formBuilder.array()` for yours attendees. [official Docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder#array)

```js
attendees: formBuilder.array([
   {
      emailAddress: {
         address: "***@***.com",
         name: "Joe Bloggs",
      },
      type: "required",
  },
]),
```